# How do I enable the AWS CLI on an EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

How do I enable the AWS CLI on an EC2 instance? After I create the EC2 instance, I can SSH into the machine, but when I try to do something like `aws s3 ls`, it prompts me to do `aws configure` first, which I then have to enter my keys. I want to be able to automate this so that I can grab additional artifacts from S3 buckets to install. Note that I am using the AWS CLI on my computer to create the EC2 instance, but I need to use the AWS CLI on the EC2 instance itself.

My AWS command to create a simple EC2 instance looks like the following (this is done on my computer).

```
aws ec2 run-instances \
 --image-id ami-14c5486b \
 --count 1 \
 --instance-type t2.micro \
 --key-name testkey \
 --subnet-id subnet-xxxxxxxx \
 --security-group-ids sg-xxxxxxxx \
 --tag-specifications 'ResourceType=instance,Tags=[{Key=Name,Value=test}]'
 --user-data file://install-software.sh
```

The `install-software.sh` looks something like the following (this is submitted to the EC2 instance).

```
#!/bin/bash

aws s3 cp s3://mybucket/some-archive.tar.gz some-archive.tar.gz
tar xf some-archive.tar.gz
sudo some-archive/bin/install.sh
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use an [instance profile](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_switch-role-ec2_instance-profiles.html) when launching your EC2 instance – if it has an instance profile attached then the AWS CLI will automatically use the permissions set in it to grant access to resources, rather than relying on your providing credentials.

Comment: Also note that it might take a while before the changes take effect, in my case it was well over 10 minutes. Until they took effect, I got an error about a missing key whenever I used the AWS CLI inside the EC2 instance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign an [instance role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html) to your instance. Give it rights to get objects from your bucket. Then the `aws cli` will get the credentials from instance metadata automatically so you won't need to configure `aws` first.